# Input-output table in Stata

Tags: stata

I have a data set, which shows if a firm *i* used inputs from firm *j* to produce some goods. There are 2 variables: firm and supplier. Both variables are unique identifiers of companies. Here is an example:

```
clear
input float(firm supplier)
1 2
2 3
4 5
end
```

Is there an efficient way to generate an input-output matrix in Stata? More specifically, I need a square matrix, which shows 1 in position (i,j) if firm *i* (row) was supplied by firm *j* (column), and 0 otherwise. For the example above, the table should look like as below, where the rows and the columns are company ID's from 1 to 5:

```
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: i corrected the typo. sorry.

Comment: Do you really need the matrix, e.g. do you want to calculate eigenvalues, etc. How big would it be?

Comment: The square matrix will be of dimension ca. 300, only. Yes, I need the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very naive algorithm, but it works.

```
clear
input float(firm supplier)
1 2
2 3
4 5
end

mat J = J(5,5,0) 

forval obs = 1/`=_N' { 
   local i = firm[`obs'] 
   local j = supplier[`obs'] 
   matrix J[`i', `j'] = 1 
} 

mat li J 

J[5,5]
    c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
r1   0   1   0   0   0
r2   0   0   1   0   0
r3   0   0   0   0   0
r4   0   0   0   0   1
r5   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Nice. Thank you for the quick response, Nick!